# Touchpad after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: updates, touchpad, 14.04

So after I put the 14.04 on my laptop yesterday, my touchpad is now not able to scroll horizontally anymore. Before it was working out of the box for me but now I can only scroll vertically.

I am using a Lenovo U310 Ideapad.

What could be the problem here? I can provide any more info if required.

Answer (score 2):

Install **Unity and Gnome Tool**. Type the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Once installed, **launch Unity Tweak Tool** and under **"Scrolling"** Tab, select **"Horizontal Scrolling"**.

Comment: That desn't seem to be an answer. Horizontal scrolling can be enabled/disabled in the default Ubuntu touchpad settings - no need to install any extras. It rather looks like a self promotion post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this via CLI, then reboot.  Worked for me.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad horiz-scroll-enabled "true"
```

Comment: Will give it a try tomorrow!

Comment: Yeah, still not working. I tried the unity-tweak method below too but in there, horizontal scrolling was allready enabled but it just does not work..